# Bitwise or between 2 sets of bytes in c

Tags: c, bitwise-or

Let's say we have

```
int *set1 = malloc(n);

int *set2 = malloc(n);
```

Then we fill these 2 sets with data. My goal is to perform bitwise or between set1 and set2.

I suppose I can't do something like

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    set1[i] = set1[i] | set2[i];
}
```

because n is the number of bytes and not the number of cells of the array.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: `n / sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Typically, you'd do `malloc(n * sizeof(int))` then **n** *would* be the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Yeah but what if n/sizeof(int) is a decimal number?

Comment: @Mark Tolonen Sorry its has to be just as I wrote it.

Comment: Is your question about the bit operation? Assuming that `n` is not wrong as in your question, why do you think this wouldn't work? What should your `n` represent? The bitnumber (which it is not)? Or the number of items in the array?

Comment: *what if n/sizeof(int) is a decimal number?*. It won't be. In C that's integer division and will always be an integer. Any fractional part of the mathematical division is truncated away.

Comment: Then `n / sizeof(int)` is the number of elements.  Assuming n is an integer, the result will an integer as well, and will be the number of integers the array supports.  If `n` is not a multiple of `sizeof(int)`, you won't OR the remaining odd bytes.  But if you want that, don't use `int`.

Comment: @ForceBru What do you mean? n is clearly the number of bytes not the elements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`set1` and `set2` are pointers to integers. You try to process bytes. This is not correct.

Try to picture the memory layout:

`malloc(1)` would allocate one byte, i.e. 8 bits.
`int *set1` declares a pointer to an int, which typically is 4 bytes, i.e. 32 bits.

A `char` typically represents 1 byte, i.e. 8 bits. So why not go with that, `char *set1` and `char *set2` ?

Comment: I was doing a project and I am using integers. I was trying to find a way in order not to have to change my entire code but if there is no other way I will use char

Comment: As far as I can see there is no other way. Unfortunately, allocating bytes and using integer pointers is ill designed in the first place. I hoped my example would show this. You risk undefined behavior (also called UB in C); Is it really such a big change to use char array instead of int array ?

Comment: You could follow the advice of Mark, if you use integer pointer then you allocate accordingly with integer type: `int *set1 = malloc(n * sizeof(int))` - that would take up more space, but my guess is that it probably does not really matter in your case. It should work fine too.

Comment: Yes man I see. Thank you for your answer. I will change it to char. I have done many other more difficult things in programming so this is gonna be relatively easy :P

Answer (score 2):

```
size_t elements = n / sizeof *set; 

for ( i = 0; i < elements; i++ )
  set1[i] = set1[i] | set2[i];
```

Notes:

- The *expression* `*set1` has type `int`; thus the expression `sizeof *set1` is the same as `sizeof (int)`.  I prefer using expressions like this instead of explicitly naming the type; it makes things easier if the type of `set1` ever needs to change.
- If `n` is the number of bytes, `n / sizeof *set1` is the number of `int` elements in the arrays.  Remember that in C integer division yields an integer result - if `n` is not a multiple of `sizeof (int)`, then the result will be the floor of `n / sizeof (int)` - i.e., `7/4 == 1`, `11/4 == 2`, etc.  It also means that you won’t access those last few bytes as part of that loop; since they don’t make up a ”complete" `int` object, that’s not a bad thing.